# C# GetExpirationDateString() returning data in short date format creating issue

Tags: c#, date, datetime, x509certificate

I have to check and ensure a certificate is not expired using the below code:

```
if (DateTime.Parse(cert.GetExpirationDateString()) <= DateTime.Now)
{
     _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Chain Certificate is Expired");
     return false;
}
```

`cert` is a instance of [X509Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=vs.110).aspx) class of .net.

Issue that am facing is [GetExpirationDateString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getexpirationdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) function gives the date of expiry in string format(which depends upon the short date format of the current culture)

If the short date format of my machine is `DD-MM-YY` it returns expiry date `21-12-2030` as `21-12-30`, `DateTime.Parse` function converts `30` to `1930` (if the expiry year is >30).

Is there a way by which I can get the certificate expiry always in `dd/mm/yyyy` format in order to avoid this issue?

Comment: Can you switch to using `x509Certificate2`? Then you can use the 'NotAfter' property, which is a proper `DateTime`.

Comment: MS Actually recommend using x509Certificate2. : _ASN.1 DER is the only certificate format supported by this class.
For most scenarios, you should use the X509Certificate2 class instead._

Comment: Thanks Glorin,Rich I used NotAfter property of X509certificate2 class and it sorted out my issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The string representation year `30` will always be converted by default to `1930` and never to `2030` when parsing a DateTime no matter how you try it. Your best bet is to do as @Glorin suggested and use [X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx). This type has a constructor that takes an instance of [X509Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=vs.110).aspx). Alternatively you can generate using one of the other constructors. Here is a code sample based on what you provided:

```
var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
if(cert2.NotAfter <= DateTime.Now)
{
     _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Chain Certificate is Expired");
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Igor that sort out my issue

Comment: Am I the only one thinking this NotAfter property is like the worst name ever??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (because i'm in french language the format for you is perhaps MM/dd/yyyy) :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(item.GetExpirationDateString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```